# server side code not firing after adding jQuery UI

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, webforms

I have a ASP.Net Dropdownlist

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                </asp:DropDownList>
```

It is executing this code on postback

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //my code here
}
```

But, this dropdownlist is not doing postback when I am adding jquery to it.

```
<script>
    $('#<%=DropDownList1.ClientID%>').selectmenu();
</script>
```

What should I do ? I want to add jquery and execute the postback server code.

Comment: what is code in `selectmenu();` , can you please provide that also

Comment: @PranayRana nothing in selectmenu(), actually it is just changing the design of asp.net dropdown into a jquery dropdown. Had I wrote wrong  ?

Comment: Check the generated HTML. I am 99% sure that the jQuery UI plugin is changing the events

Comment: I did'nt understand. What do I need to check ?

Comment: Open the page in your browser of choice and check the HTML -  through the developer console (normally F12)

Comment: can you please try out solution suggested

Comment: @PranayRana yes, I am trying continously

Comment: Ok, let me know if you face any issues

Comment: @PranayRana, both of your solutions are not working.

Comment: ok let me see as I left working on asp.net log back , will try to help you

Comment: try out this : `document.getElementById('<%= DropDownList1.ClientID %>').onchange();`

Comment: is that worked ??

Comment: It refreshes the page continously automatically,not working

Comment: @PranayRana Sir, any other suggestion for this ?

Answer (score 0):

try as below change event fire can trigger serverside event

```
document.getElementById('<%= DropDownList1.ClientID %>').onchange();
```

or

```
$('#<%=DropDownList1.ClientID%>').change(function() { return true;});
```

or this can also help , it sold way and i dont like it much and try if it above one not work

```
$('#<%=DropDownList1.ClientID%>').change(function() {
  __doPostBack("<%#=DropDownList1.ClientID %>","");
});
```